# get value from variable dynamically

Tags: javascript

I'm trying, but unsuccessfully, to get the value of a variable, where the variable name is dynamic

```
var v_1playerName = document.getElementById("id_1playerName").value;
var v_2playerName = document.getElementById("id_2playerName").value; 
for (i = 1; i <=5 i++) {
    alert(window["v_"+i+"playerName"]);
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You are trying to alert the string `v_1playerName` and not the value of the variable.

Comment: did you try `var windowName = "v_"+i+"playerName"; alert(window[windowName]);` ?

Comment: At this point I just want to know the value of the variable. It's in a simple function that as exactly this code, nothing else.

Comment: @ochi: how would i get the value of the html field like that?

Comment: You are trying to address the wrong problem. You can do this with `eval`, but that's evil (even if you do not have a security issue, it makes your code slower); but what you really should be doing is having either an object or array to hold both of your values.

Comment: @ochi: Only if it is in global scope; if it is in a function, `var` would make them local variables, in which case you can't reach them on `window`.

Comment: If you can use jQuery then you can use `$('[id$="playerName"]');`

Comment: @Amadan: That's a good tip, thank you, much easier for sure!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple thing would be to put the variables in an array and then use the for loop to show them.

```
var v_1playerName = document.getElementById("id_1playerName").value;
var v_2playerName = document.getElementById("id_2playerName").value; 
var nameArray = [v_1playerName,v_2playerName];
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
alert(nameArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: @PedroSales You could do something like this : `code` var playerArray = document.querySelectorAll('div.playerElement'); playerArray.forEach(p => alert(p.value);)`code`

Answer (score 1):

Accessing variables through `window` isn't a great idea.

Just store the values in an object and access them using square notation:

```
var obj = {
  v_1playerName: 0,
  v_2playerName: 3
}

obj['v_' + 2 + 'playerName']; // 3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep named references to things you could use an object.

```
var playerNames = {};
playerNames['p1'] = document.getElementById("id_1playerName").value;
playerNames['p2'] = document.getElementById("id_2playerName").value;
for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
  // dynamically get access to each value
  alert.log(playerNames['p' + i])
}
```